# How can I verify a user and password in AD without PHP ldap_bind?

Tags: php

I have a php file that connects and binds to AD with a service account no problem on that.
I have an HTML form asking for `user name` and `password`.
I need a way to verify the user's credentials against AD
when the user enters their user name and password in the form.

I cannot use the `ldap_bind` function, because our users don't have the permission to do that.

Suppose PHP has an `auth` class, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work. Can anyone help me with that? If `auth` class doesn't work, what other codes can I use to verify credentials and add it to my PHP page?
The following is my php page:

```
<?php

// Connect to AD========================================================

include('studentFormAuth.html');

$ldapusername = 'service_account_name';

$ldappassword = "service_account_password";

$server = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';

$domain = '@abc.com';

$port = 389;

$connection = ldap_connect($server, $port);

if (!$connection) {

    exit('Connection failed');

}

// Settings for AD======================================================

ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

$bind = @ldap_bind($connection, $ldapusername.$domain, $ldappassword);

if (!$bind) {

    exit('Binding failed');

}

// Verify user credentials auth function=============================================

$auth = new Auth($connection, $_POST['usern'].$domain, $_POST['password']);

// begin validation 

$auth->start();

if ($auth->getAuth()) {

    // content for validated users

    echo 'user name is: ' $_POST['usern'].$domain;

} else {

    echo 'Cannot verify user';
}

// log users out

$auth->logout();
```

Comment: what happneds when you do ldap_bind even though its not allowed ? maybe the exception thrown can help you

Comment: I got "Binding failed", no other errors.

Comment: oh sry I misunderstood I tohught users with the correct credentials could use ldap_bind